# How to set the path while working on images in Flask on localhost as well as ibm cloud

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, flask, ibm-cloud, cloudant

This application was running fine till yesterday but today it isn't working. No changes have been made in backend or front end. The site [Output is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgLSC.png). I am trying to use open cv to extract 4 sub images from a image which has been uploaded in ../static/uploads folder. While the extracted 4 images are stored in ../static/extracted folder. Now my concern is, yesterday the code was running but today it isn't working. And while deploying to the ibm cloud, I could not find open cv. "cv2 module not found". Can someone please help me improve this code.

app.py code:

```
from cloudant import Cloudant
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import atexit
import os
import json
from ocr_core import ocr_core


UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/static/uploads/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='')

db_name = 'mydb'
client = None
db = None

if 'VCAP_SERVICES' in os.environ:
    vcap = json.loads(os.getenv('VCAP_SERVICES'))
    print('Found VCAP_SERVICES')
    if 'cloudantNoSQLDB' in vcap:
        creds = vcap['cloudantNoSQLDB'][0]['credentials']
        user = creds['username']
        password = creds['password']
        url = 'https://' + creds['host']
        client = Cloudant(user, password, url=url, connect=True)
        db = client.create_database(db_name, throw_on_exists=False)
elif "CLOUDANT_URL" in os.environ:
    client = Cloudant(os.environ['CLOUDANT_USERNAME'], os.environ['CLOUDANT_PASSWORD'], url=os.environ['CLOUDANT_URL'], connect=True)
    db = client.create_database(db_name, throw_on_exists=False)
elif os.path.isfile('vcap-local.json'):
    with open('vcap-local.json') as f:
        vcap = json.load(f)
        print('Found local VCAP_SERVICES')
        creds = vcap['services']['cloudantNoSQLDB'][0]['credentials']
        user = creds['username']
        password = creds['password']
        url = 'https://' + creds['host']
        client = Cloudant(user, password, url=url, connect=True)
        db = client.create_database(db_name, throw_on_exists=False)

# On IBM Cloud Cloud Foundry, get the port number from the environment variable PORT
# When running this app on the local machine, default the port to 8000
port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return render_template('upload.html', msg='No file selected')
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            return render_template('upload.html', msg='No file selected')

        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            file.save(os.path.join(os.getcwd() + UPLOAD_FOLDER, file.filename))
            extracted_text = ocr_core(file)
            return render_template('upload.html',
                                   msg='Successfully processed',
                                   extracted_text=extracted_text,
                                   img_src=UPLOAD_FOLDER + file.filename)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('upload.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

ocr_py.py:

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

#UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/static'
def ocr_core(filename):
    #text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename)) 
    val=str(filename)
    val=list(val)
    naam=""
    tt=0
    for i in range(15,len(val)):
            if(val[i]!="'"):
                naam+=val[i]
                if(val[i]=='g'):
                    tt=1
            if(tt==1):
                break
    image = cv2.imread("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/static/uploads/" +str(naam))
    k=randint(0, 999999) 
    cropped1 = image[290:500, 320:1540]
    cv2.imwrite("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/static/extracted/name"+str(k)+".png", cropped1)
    name=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/static/extracted/name"+str(k)+".png"))
    cropped2 = image[470:700, 670:2640]
    cv2.imwrite("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/static/extracted/amount"+str(k)+".png", cropped2)
    amount=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/static/extracted/amount"+str(k)+".png"))
    cropped3 = image[850:1000, 480:1040]
    cv2.imwrite("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/static/extracted/acc_no"+str(k)+".png", cropped3)
    acc_no=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/static/extracted/acc_no"+str(k)+".png"))
    cropped5 = image[500:850, 2940:4500]
    cv2.imwrite("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/static/extracted/amt_num"+str(k)+".png", cropped5)
    amt_num=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/static/extracted/amt_num"+str(k)+".png"))
    acc_no1=""
    lnum=["1","0","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
    for i in range(0,len(acc_no)):
        if(str(acc_no[i]) in lnum):
            acc_no1+=acc_no[i]
    l=[name,acc_no,amt_num]
    df = pd.read_csv("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/jobchahiye.csv")
    df.loc[df.Account== int(l[1]), 'Amount'] -=int(l[2])
    df.loc[df.Name== str(l[0]), 'Amount'] +=int(l[2])
    df.to_csv("/home/sahil/CheckCheque-deploy/jobchahiye.csv", index=False) 
    return l
```

Comment: Is the app run as Docker / Kubernetes container, on a VM or as Cloud Foundry? How was it deployed? What is in your requirements.txt?

Comment: It's not yet deployed. Yesterday while deploying using cloudant on ibm cloud I got the error saying no module named cv2 found. It was running perfectly fine till yesterday on localhost. Today it isn't running on localhost itself and thus couldn't try on cloud. The backend work gets done but just the image isn't loading on front page.

Comment: How do you plan to deploy? What were the commands you tried? What were the exact error messages? Please add by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a dependency on either `opencv-python` or `opencv-contrib-python`. As such it needs to be installed as a pre-requisite on any machine that you want to run your application.

On localhost you do this with `pip`, but if you are not running something like `virtualenv` then all installs will be to the global space, and conflicts can easily arise, resulting in you not being able to run anything.

For cloud deployments you specify pip prerequisites in your `requirements.txt` file